# Question about queries with multiple where clauses, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class called Gym

```
class Gym < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gym_users
  has_many :users, :through => :gym_users

  validates :name, :address1, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :website, :presence => true

  def has_admin_access?(user)
    user.present? && gym_users.where(:user_id => user.id, :gym_role_id => 3)
  end
end
```

I want to modify the has_admin_access method to look for a gym_role_id of 3 or 4.  The other question I have is how do I do a less than or greater than?

Is there a cheat sheet online somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
user.present? && gym_users.where(:user_id => user.id, :gym_role_id => [3, 4])
```

Try [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) gem for writing less than and great than queries along with symbols. Tutorial available at http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch

MetaWhere isn't supported as of Rails 3.1. A more up to date alternative is [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel).

Comment: So if you pass it multiple values in an array it will automatically create an in statement?

Comment: yup it does use the in clause with array